# Proper way of importing from one file into two files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

i have a question regarding imports.

**Assume following structure:**

- /src/definitions.py
- /src/class.py
- main.py

**definitions.py** contains several constants which need to be imported

in **class.py** i import:

```
from . definitions import A, B, C
```

however i need A, B, C in **main.py** aswell. which one of those two is the proper way?

1)

```
from src.class import MyClass
from src.definitions import A, B, C, D, E
```

or

2)

```
from src.class import MyClass, A, B, C
from src.definitions import D, E
```

obviously 1 and 2 work, but which way is the right one

Comment: Generally prefer to import them from the module they are defined in. An exception to that would be when values from a bunch of modules are imported (usually into an `__init__.py`) into a common module essentially just for the purpose of 're-exporting' them under a simpler namespace

Comment: side note: `class.py` is bad name ...

Comment: IMO, option 1 makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Doubled imports are never recommended, I would go with the first one

```
from src.class import MyClass
from src.definitions import A, B, C, D, E
```

You should import the file in wich the class (or variable) originally belongs.
Hope it helps!